# Can I connect esp32 to a phone USB charger?

Tags: esp32

I have a USB charger. Is it ok to connect it as a power supply for esp32?

Edit: i have a dev board esp32

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In principle yes (see also comment in update).

The voltage is ok (5V), typically USB, and it doesn't differ from the output of a computer USB port.

The output current is max 2000 mA, so check if your project (ESP + related hardware powered by this USB), is not exceeding 2000 mA. The ESP needs much less than 2000 mA, so if you didn't have a lot of external components or motors than you will be safe.

**Update**

Important omment from Sim Sson: The bare esp32 is not 5V-tolerant, so using a usb-charger is only ok for esp modules that have a voltage regulator onboard.

Comment: I think you might have missed a zero there. The charger says "2000mA".

Comment: @hooskworks Thanks for the notification, and yes I did (updated my answer).

Comment: The bare esp32 is not 5V-tolerant, so using a usb-charger is only ok for esp modules that have a voltage regulator onboard.

Comment: @SimSon I was assuming he will connect the USB cable into the plug (thus having some kind of development board). But I will add it to the answer, thanks a lot.

Comment: @yuria Hopefully he does, but he didn't tell. Thanks for adding that point, it might be useful for others having this question in future!

Comment: @SimSon True, a year ago I possibly wouldn't realize it myself

Comment: @SimSon Bare esp32 is only the rectangle right?if i have a micro usb,then it is the dev board?

Comment: @yuria yes, a device with usb socket is always supposed to be 5V tolerant as that's part of the standard